# Java equivalent to NumPy

Tags: java, math, numerical-analysis

In the Python world, if I have some number crunching to do, I use NumPy and it's friends like Matplotlib.

Now I have an Android/Java application and the need arises to crunch some numbers and I am wondering what I should do. Roll my own wrappers around Arrays of Floats?!? That sounds horrible. I want something more high-level.

Operations that I would need to perform are typical vector-scalar or vector-vector operations:

- find the maximum element in a vector
- calculate the sum of all elements in a vector
- dot/cross/element-wise product of two vectors

Later I might be interested in advanced operations like FFT or matrix operations, but right now I am looking for a solid basic library to prevent me from reinventing the wheel.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try Googling `java linear algebra library`?

Answer (score 3):

The [nd4j.org](http://nd4j.org/) API tries to mimic the semantics of Numpy, Matlab and scikit-learn. [deeplearning4j.org](https://deeplearning4j.org/) is based on nd4j.

Comment: Both the links are dead, I think the new url is https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/nd4j/tutorials/quickstart

Answer (score 2):

[NM Dev](https://nm.dev) is a Java numerical library (commercial, community and academical licenses ).

The open source of it is available at:
https://github.com/nmdev2020/SuanShu

Comment: Can you point out the relevant features requested in the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Java numerical libraries.

Please see here for an overview:
http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/OpenSourceNumeric.html

(I don't have the reputation to post more than 2 links, so just linking to the page containing the links.)